# esp32 websocket get weird chars from web js

Tags: websocket, esp32

I am using an es32 with web server and a simple html page with a slider which send some data to esp. The issue is that on esp side I get some unwanted and weird chars which broke my logic some times.

Html code

```
<div class="container">
<input id="r" type="range" min="600" max="6000" step="10" value="650" oninput="sendTRR();">
<br>
<br>
<input id="t" type="range" min="35" max="99" step="1" value="35" oninput="sendTRT();">
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

JS code

```
    function sendTRR() {
        var r = parseInt(document.getElementById('r').value).toString(10);
        RPMValue = r;
        document.getElementById("RPMValue").innerHTML = RPMValue;
        var data_back = 'r' + r;
        websocket.send(data_back);
        console.log('data back', data_back);
}

function sendTRT() {
    var t = parseInt(document.getElementById('t').value).toString(10);  
    TMPValue = t;
    document.getElementById("TMPValue").innerHTML = TMPValue;
    var data_back = 't' + t;
    websocket.send(data_back);
    console.log('data back', data_back);
}
```

esp32 code

```
void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t * data, size_t len) {
  String str = (char*)data;
  if (str.substring(0, 1) == "r"){
    data_send = str.substring(1, 5);
    Serial.println(str);
    Serial.println(str.substring(1, 5).toInt());
    if (str.substring(1, 5).toInt() < 1000) {
      
      data_send = "0" + data_send;
      RPM = data_send.substring(0, 4).toInt();
      //TMP = data_send.substring(4, 6).toInt();
      data_send1 = "<" + String(RPM) + ">";
      Serial.println(data_send1);
      //set_temp(TMP);
    }
    else {
      RPM = data_send.substring(0, 4).toInt();
      //TMP = data_send.substring(4, 6).toInt();
      data_send1 = "<" + String(RPM) + ">";
      Serial.println(data_send1);
      //set_temp(TMP);
    }
  }
  
  else if (str.substring(0, 1) == "t"){
    data_send = str.substring(1, 3);
    Serial.println(str);
    Serial.println(str.substring(1, 3).toInt());
    TMP = data_send.toInt();
    set_temp(TMP);
    
  }
  
  else if ( str == "connect_ask_dtc") {
...
```

If i connect with lap and open chrome console i have clean values printed

```
Connection opened
script_service.js:75 data back r5310
script_service.js:75 data back r1390
script_service.js:75 data back r5170
script_service.js:75 data back r830
......
```

But when print from esp i get some things added to the values.

```
r2870&
2870
<2870>
r5480atform
dbankﾭ⸮xV⸮⸮;⸮? 
5480
<5480>
r600vices
googleﾭ⸮xV⸮⸮$
600
<600>
r6000
6000
<6000>
r6004⸮⸮
6004
<6004>
r5910ices
googleaﾭ⸮xV⸮⸮;⸮? 
5910
<5910>
r6000ices
googleﾭ⸮xV⸮⸮$
6000
<6000>
<6000>
r5310
5310
<5310>
r1390
1390
<1390>
r5170
5170
<5170>
r830ffice365com
830
<830>
```

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks in adavnce